# Android Studio 3.5 What happened to my buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout

I created 3 ImageButtons that look find in my layout in Android Studio, but when the app is loaded onto my phone, the buttons are tiny.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/CountryList"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/clearCountryButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:hint="Country"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/clearCountryButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/CountryList"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/CountryList"
        tools:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete" />
```

I left off the next two AutoCompleteTextView and ImageButton pairs for brevity.

Here is how it looks in Android Studio...

[image]

And here is how it looks on my phone...

[image]

I can't see what I am doing wrong. Anyone?

Jeff

Comment: Android Studio is showing you `android:drawable/ic_input_delete`, which you defined via `tools:src`. Your layout does not define a content for this image (`android:src`), and your question does not show if and how you are populating those widgets at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_input_delete"
```

instead of using

```
tools:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"
```

or

```
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"
```

it's a deprecated method for drawing vector drawables and even Android studio suggests to change it.

Comment: Thanks so much. Not sure how that got in there. I actually had to use the following exact syntax: app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete" - maybe that was a typo in your first line. As it is, your first line did not work without the "android:" part added.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `tools:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"`
with `android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"`

Example:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/clearCountryButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/CountryList"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/CountryList"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete" />
```

Comment: android:src is deprecated